# How to remove last string in list in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose,

a = ["Power is nothing"]

How to remove last string in variable 'a' which is 'g'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use list slicing:

```
a = a[0][:-1]
```

`a[0]` selects the first element in your list. in your case, a[0] is "Power is nothing". Then [:-1] returns a new string without the last letter.

You can check the documentation for any detail regarding list slicing in python

Comment: That's wrong. It removes the whole variable just like 'clear' function.

Comment: This should work a[0][:-1:]

Comment: That works but i did not understand. Those slices are very unique. I can't understand them.

Comment: @M.Husnain: Do a web search on "Python slice". Ask for details if you do not understand, but try your own research first. [Here is some of the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) (scroll down until you get to "slice").

Comment: uhm well you have a string inside a list, that's why you need to go `a[0][:-1]`